# Is it possible to install pcsc-lite 1.8.13 on Raspbian OS?

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pcsc

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi project. I'm trying to install a [driver package](http://www.acs.com.hk/download-driver-unified/5128/ACS-Unified-PKG-Lnx-110-P.zip) for ACR1251U-A1 NFC tag.

This package requires to install pcsc-lite package at first. But as I understand after a search on the internet, pcsc-lite 1.8.13 is not available for Raspbian OS.

My supervisor persists that pcsc-lite 1.8.13 should be installed on Raspberry Pi to make NFC tag work.

Is it possible to install it on a Raspbian? If it is so, could you help me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to install `pcscd` daemon and using `pcsc-lite` [wrapper in NodeJS](https://github.com/santigimeno/node-pcsclite) on Raspbian (`Linux raspberrypi 3.18.11-v7+ #781 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:07:59 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux`) using Raspberry Pi B+ and Raspberry Pi 2.

Here an extract of the *Requirements installation* from the [full guide of mine project on GitHub](https://github.com/goodotcom/rfid-reader-http):

> 2. Install PC/SC and libnfc (references: [nfc-tools](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Libnfc#Debian_.2F_Ubuntu), [libnfc](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc)):
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install pcscd libusb-dev libpcsclite1 libpcsclite-dev dh-autoreconf
>
>    cd /opt/
>    sudo wget https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/archive/libnfc-1.7.1.zip
>    sudo unzip libnfc-1.7.1.zip
>    cd libnfc-libnfc-1.7.1/
>    sudo autoreconf -vis
>    sudo ./configure --with-drivers=all
>    sudo make
>    sudo make install
>    ```
>
>    Additionaly, you may need to grant permissions to your user to drive the device.
>      Under GNU/Linux systems, if you use `udev`, you could use the provided `udev` rules.
>          e.g. under Debian: `sudo cp /opt/libnfc-libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/udev/42-pn53x.rules /lib/udev/rules.d/`
> 3. Make sure the NFC reader is properly recognized:
>
>    ```
>    sudo nfc-list
>    ```
>
>    1. To fix: `error while loading shared libraries: libnfc.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` ([reference](http://seckev.blog.com/2013/04/17/installation-mfterm-with-acr122u-on-kali-linux-system/))
>
>       ```
>       echo '/usr/local/lib' | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/usr-local-lib.conf && sudo ldconfig
>       ```
>    2. If you have kernel version > 3.5, probably `pcscd` and also `nfc-list` will report this error: `Unable to claim USB interface (Device or resource busy)` due to the automatic load of `pn533` driver.
>
>       To read the `pcscd` dameon output you can run it using: `pcscd -f -d`
>
>       1. Check which kernel version is installed: `uname -a`
>       2. Blacklist `pn533` and `nfc` drivers (references: [Arch Linux wiki Touchatag RFID Reader](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchatag_RFID_Reader), [nfc-tools forum](http://forums.nfc-tools.org/post/5308/#p5308)):
>
>          ```
>          sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-libnfc.conf
>          ```
>
>          Add the following lines:
>
>          blacklist pn533
>                blacklist nfc
>       3. Disable kernel modules:
>
>          ```
>          modprobe -r pn533 nfc
>          ```
>       4. Restart the `pcscd` daemon: `sudo service pcscd restart`